# Buttons that changes state to refresh Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this sample:

http://jsfiddle.net/JfGVE/1017/

**CODE HTML:**

```
<i class="fa fa-circle-o circle crad" id="radio"></i>
<i class="fa fa-circle-o circle crad" id="radio"></i>
<i class="fa fa-circle-o circle crad" id="radio"></i>
<i class="fa fa-circle-o circle crad" id="radio"></i>
<i class="fa fa-circle-o circle crad" id="radio"></i>
```

**CODE JS:**

```
 var firstButtonObject = localStorage.getItem('class');
       if(firstButtonObject){
            $('.crad').addClass(firstButtonObject);       
       }

       $('.crad').click(taskFunction);
       function taskFunction(){
             if ( $( this ).hasClass( "fa-circle" ) ) {
                  $( this ).removeClass('fa-circle').addClass('fa-circle-o');
                   localStorage.setItem('class', 'fa-circle-o');
             }else{
                  $(this).removeClass('fa-circle-o').addClass('fa-circle');
                  localStorage.setItem('class', 'fa-circle');
                }
        }
```

The problem is that when I click on a button and then ... all are colored refresh
I want to stay just those that clicked ...

For example, if I click on the 3 buttons of 5 to be a full circle only 3

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to have only one button clicked at a time?

Answer (score 0):

```js
 
       var defineClass = '';
            $('.crad').each(function( index){
               defineClass = localStorage.getItem('class' + index);
               $(this).addClass(defineClass)
            
            });      
       
   
       $('.crad').click(taskFunction);
       function taskFunction(){
             if ( $( this ).hasClass( "fa-circle" ) ) {
                  $( this ).removeClass('fa-circle').addClass('fa-circle-o');
                   localStorage.setItem('class' + $(this).index(), 'fa-circle-o');
             }else{
                  $(this).removeClass('fa-circle-o').addClass('fa-circle');
                  localStorage.setItem('class'+$(this).index(), 'fa-circle');
                }
            }
```

Store class info based on index wise.